# Convert CvImagePtr* (CvImage) channel to IplImage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have extracted an Image message using cv_bridge as this:

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::MONO8);
```

and i could convert it to an IplImage using:

```
IplImage *image2 = NULL;
allocateit( &image2, frame_size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
image2->imageData = (char *) cv_ptr->image.data;
```

where `allocateit` is a function to allocate space.
My problem comes when I want to read a color image as this:

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
IplImage *image2 = NULL;
allocateit( &image2, frame_size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
```

and want to copy one channel of `*cv_ptr` to the image to the IplImage `*image2`. I have tried:

```
image2->imageData = (char *) cv_ptr->image.data;
```

but it crashes,

```
cv::cvtColor(cv_ptr->image.data,image2->imageData,CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

but does not compile,

```
int from_to[] = {0,0};
cv::mixChannels(&(cv_ptr->image.data),1,image2,1, from_to,1);
```

does not compile either.

What would you recommend me to do?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43071/convert-cvimageptr*-(cvimage)-channel-to-iplimage/) by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know I should use cv::Mat, in fact I want to use it. But specifically in this problem I cannot use it. (see: http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/81826).

Anyway I found a (not elegant) way  to convert it :

```
                for(int ko=0; ko< frame_size.width*frame_size.height ; ko++)
{
        image2->imageData[ko] = (char) cv_ptr->image.data[ko*3];
}
```

---

Originally posted by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) with karma: 187 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2013-11-05**:
what is frame_size?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might find more help on the [OpenCV support forum](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/messages).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I strongly recommend using new OpenCV 2.x API, specially the `Mat` data structure instead of `IplImage`. It's easy to use [split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#split) function to access different image channels and the assignment operator or `clone()` function to copy reference/data.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3